# display letters in ascending order in java

Tags: java

i would like to display letters ether they are in ascending order or not in ascending order, i'm having problem to compare the array's index. in this case i'm using bubble sort technic and modify them.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print( "#Enter text : " );
        String text = BIO.getString();

        while ( ! text.equals( "END" ) )
          {
            boolean inorder = false;
            // Convert the above string to a char array.
            char[] arr = text.toCharArray();

            for (int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++)
            { //Check pair

               if ( arr[i] > arr[i+1] ) 
                 { 

                    System.out.print("letters in ascending order");
                    inorder = true;

                   }

             }

              if ( ! inorder )
                   { 
                    System.out.print("letters not in ascending order");

                   }

               break;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: so what is your question? Your solution seems to correct.

Comment: As a fun fact, [Aegilops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aegilops) is the [longest word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_English#Words_with_certain_characteristics_of_notable_length) with letters in alphabetic order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this looks like homework, I'll limit my answer to a couple of hints.

Your logic is the wrong way round. You should assume that the array *is* in the ascending order until you see evidence to the contrary.

Also, that `print` inside the loop can get called multiple times. You probably don't want that.

Other than this, you're almost there.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently deciding they are in order before you even finish comparing all the letters in the string. Try assuming that they are in order and changing the flag to false once you find one that is NOT in order.

Also, your break statement is gonna quit your while loop after the first iteration.